# Shell scripting with Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm wondering if there are any node framework or node lib out there that I can use to write a shell scripts? For example, I have bash shell program to install Graphite and OpenTSDB RRD tools, I would like to use node.js for it, is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at [shelljs](https://github.com/arturadib/shelljs) - it implemets shell and gnu coreutils-like functions.
Together with coffeescript it can look very similar to a shell script:

```
if not which 'git'
  echo 'Sorry, this script requires git'
  exit 1

# Copy files to release dir
mkdir '-p', 'out/Release'
cp '-R', 'stuff/*', 'out/Release'

# Replace macros in each .js file
cd 'lib'
for file in ls '*.js'
  sed '-i', 'BUILD_VERSION', 'v0.1.2', file
  sed '-i', /.*REMOVE_THIS_LINE.*\n/, '', file
  sed '-i', /.*REPLACE_LINE_WITH_MACRO.*\n/, cat 'macro.js', file
cd '..'

# Run external tool synchronously
if (exec 'git commit -am "Auto-commit"').code != 0
  echo 'Error: Git commit failed'
  exit 1
```

Comment: thanks @Andrey Sidorov, look very promising, I'm going to try out this lib.

Answer (score 3):

You should check out [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) which is a toolkit for helping people write build and other scripts in node.js. There are a ton of plugins to help you easily do interesting things.

That being said, if you know Bash, I'd just stick with bash.

Check out this [interesting thread on Twitter about Bash vs. Grunt scripting](https://twitter.com/substack/status/390453183966765056)

**What I Use Grunt For**

- Running Lint Tools
- Running JS Unit Tests
- Running Pre-Processors (sass, require.js, uglify, etc.)

**What I use Capistrano`*` For**

- Deploying code to production environments

**What I use Bash`**` for**

- Setting up servers and running them, etc.

---

- `*` [capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) + git or [chef](https://github.com/opscode/chef) or whatever
- `**` bash or whatever other tools you'd want to use

Comment: would you please explain more why you would stick with bash if I already know Bash? Is there any advantages of using bash over grunt?

Comment: 1. Executing binary programs on your server is significantly harder in asynchronous javascript that it is in bash. 2. Grunt/node.js are still pre 1.0 and have changing APIs (grunt more so than node) 3. Bash is a general purpose tool available on many systems whereas node.js and grunt are not likely to be installed on many systems.

Comment: Docker https://www.docker.com/ cuts a lot of cruft out of all of this though. (** and *)

Answer (score 2):

There are many, among the most popular there's [`commander`](https://github.com/visionmedia/commander.js)

```
npm install --save commander
```

Then writing the command is pretty easy:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var program = require('commander');

program
  .version('0.0.1')
  .option('-f, --foo', 'enable some foo')
  .option('-b, --bar', 'enable some bar')
  .option('-B, --baz', 'enable some baz');

program.on('--foo', function(){
  console.log('Stuff!');
});
```

Comment: This is not quite I'm looking for. I'm looking for a node framework that can help me to write shell script. For example: I have this script written in bash https://github.com/gdbtek/setup-graphite/blob/master/ubuntu.bash and I would like to make this in node. If it is too much using Node.js, I think it would be better for me to stay in bash scripting.